# How to calculate least square means (adjusted means) MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mean, least-squares, adjustment

In several papers I read that when analysing a variable (lets say the response to a medication) means across groups should be adjusted for confounding factors like age, gender etc. (if these groups have different characteristics, i.e. different age, gender, etc.)

[Here](http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/lsmeans2.htm) I read that means that have been corrected for such imbalances are called adjusted means or least squares means. Adjusted means are predicted values from a multiple regression equation (hence, the name least squares means).

Could you please tell me how to calculate these adjusted means in MATLAB?
Please consider that I have 4 groups and I should adjust for more than 2 factors.

Comment: The description is vague. Could you give a mathematical definition of the adjusted means, please? Or a link to some document that does this?

Comment: @CST-Link Please check this link (also in the question now) to understand better what I mean http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/lsmeans2.htm

Comment: Nevermind, found something: http://www.mlrv.ua.edu/2012/vol38_1/MLRV_38_1_B_p_8_15_ClasonMundfrom.pdf